# Наложение двух картинок (C#)

Tags: c#

Делаю программу. Понадобилось наложение двух картинок, которые будут задаваться в методе. Вот как пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я попробовал что-то в SFML, но не выходило.
Нет идей даже как это сделать.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так. Картинки одного размера:

```
var image1 = Image.FromFile("1.jpg");
var image2 = Image.FromFile("2.jpg");

var image3 = new Bitmap(image1.Width, image1.Height);
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image3))
{
    var matrix = new ColorMatrix();
    var attrs = new ImageAttributes();

    // нижнюю картинку рисуем непрозрачной
    matrix.Matrix33 = 1f;
    attrs.SetColorMatrix(matrix);
    graphics.DrawImage(image1, new Rectangle(0, 0, image3.Width, image3.Height), 0, 0, image3.Width, image3.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attrs);

    // верхнюю рисуем полупрозрачной
    matrix.Matrix33 = 0.5f;
    attrs.SetColorMatrix(matrix);
    graphics.DrawImage(image2, new Rectangle(0, 0, image3.Width, image3.Height), 0, 0, image3.Width, image3.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attrs);
}

image3.Save("3.jpg");
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но у меня вылетает ошибка Out Of Memory..

Comment: какого размера у вас картинки? я пробовал с 480х640

Comment: Я использовал 128x128

Comment: странно, на какой строчке вылетает исключение? вы добавили этот код в свою программу, или создали новую с нуля и с только моим кодом?

Comment: Я скопировал в свою программу ваш код. Хотел спросить -  а поддерживает ли этот метод файлы BMP?

Comment: Всё, понял. Спасибо. Поменял на jpg и всё заработало